# C++ Using if/else statements in function definition to return smallest number

Tags: c++, algorithm, if-statement, min

For my homework assignment in C++, my goal is to write a program the inputs three integers and passes them to a function that returns the smallest number. This is only my 3rd week of C++, so I don't know much.

In addition, I'm only allowed to start off with `#include<iostream>` and `using namespace std`. I had been at this for hours,this just doesn't come easy to me. I've tried so many different things and I've only been getting errors...

This is the code I have so far that I actually understand:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fsmallestNumber(int);

int main() {
    int numberOne;
    int numberTwo;
    int numberThree;
    int smallestNumber;

    cout << "Enter in 3 numbers and I will find the smallest of all three" << endl;
    cin >> numberOne >> numberTwo >> numberThree;


    cout << "The smallest of all three numbers is " << smallestNumber << endl;

}

int fsmallestNumber(int sn){


}
```

I'm confused on how to use the if/else statements to find the smallest number, and how to return the smallest number back into the function to print it out.

Comment: What have you tried? There doesn't seem to be any code here that attempts to solve it. What part specifically do you need help with?

Comment: [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for a lot of helpful information that explain "how to use the if/else statements".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fsmallestNumber( int, int, int );

int main() 
{
    int numberOne;
    int numberTwo;
    int numberThree;
    int smallestNumber;

    cout << "Enter in 3 numbers and I will find the smallest of all three" << endl;
    cin >> numberOne >> numberTwo >> numberThree;

    smallestNumber = fsmallestNumber( numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree );

    cout << "The smallest of all three numbers is " << smallestNumber << endl;
}

int fsmallestNumber( int x, int y, int z )
{
    int smallest = x;

    if ( y < smallest ) smallest = y;
    if ( z < smallest ) smallest = z;

    return smallest;
}
```

The function has to accept three arguments. So it must be declared with three parameters.

If you need to include an else statement then the function can be written like

```
int fsmallestNumber( int x, int y, int z )
{
    int smallest;

    if ( not ( y < x || z < x ) )
    {
        smallest = x;
    }
    else if ( not ( z < y ) )
    {
        smallest = y;
    }
    else
    {
        smallest = z;
    }

    return smallest;
}
```

Pay attention to that the C++ standard library already has suitable algorithm `std::min` declared in the header `<algorithm>`. So you could just write

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

smallestNumber = std::min( { numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree } );
```

Comment: @Maxine Such things can be Googled or found with the Stack Overflow search function. This is the first Google result for "c++ function arguments": http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/